# code not running as another thread is accessing it

Tags: c#

I am trying to Write on an xml inside the zip File

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String strPathofZip = @"C:/Work/Zip/PATHDATA DT2.zip";
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(strPathofZip);
    zipFile.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (ZipEntry ze in zipFile)
    {
        if (ze.Name == "SOURCEDATACONFIG.XML")
        {
            StreamReader s = new StreamReader(zipFile.GetInputStream(ze));
            {
                XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XDoc.Load(s);
                XmlNodeList NodeList = XDoc.SelectNodes(@"R/I");
                foreach (XmlNode Node in NodeList)
                {
                    XmlElement Elem = (XmlElement)Node;

                    Elem.SetAttribute("url", "77");
                    //Elem.SetAttribute("url", "3");
                }
                XDoc.Save("SOURCEDATACONFIG.XML");
            }

            zipFile.Add(ze.Name);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(zipFile.Name);
    zipFile.CommitUpdate();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The code Runs in the console application and the Xml is updated
but

if I try to  use the same code as a function in windows form...
it throws error

```
private void settingAttributeinZipppedXML(string ZipPath)
{
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ZipPath);
    zipFile.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (ZipEntry ze in zipFile)
    {
        if (ze.Name == "SOURCEDATACONFIG.XML")
        {
            using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(zipFile.GetInputStream(ze)))
            {
                XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XDoc.Load(s);
                XmlNodeList NodeList = XDoc.SelectNodes(@"R/I");
                foreach (XmlNode Node in NodeList)
                {
                    XmlElement Elem = (XmlElement)Node;
                    Elem.SetAttribute("url", "12");
                }
                XDoc.Save("SOURCEDATACONFIG.XML");
            }
            zipFile.Add(ze.Name);
        }
    }
    zipFile.CommitUpdate();
}
```

The Error is

> Could not find file 'C:\Work\Zip\PATHDATA DT2.zip.561.tmp'.

And 1 more thing: If I debug the code for some time the program runs.

What would cause this behavior?

The Stack Trace is here..

```
StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
       at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.DiskArchiveStorage.ConvertTemporaryToFinal()
       at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.RunUpdates()
       at ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile.CommitUpdate()
       at SDEProfilePathEditor.SDEProfilePathEditorForm.settingAttributeinZipppedXML(String ZipPath)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at SDEProfilePathEditor.Program.Main()
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `using (StreamReader s...` in the console application example as well, or is it a typo? It kinda makes a difference...

Comment: is that the value of your ZipPath argument? Where do you set its value?  I assume the correct path is `C:\Work\Zip\PATHDATA DT2.zip`

Comment: Your two applications differ obviously.  The path that it can't find is not the same path you have in the console app.  Try figuring out why you're specifying a different path in the WinForms app.

Comment: Yes the argument in the Form is this path only... As I told you that it runs sometime but not most of the time...

Comment: When i Debug it for some time and check the values... it shows C:\Work\Zip\PATHDATA DT2.zip and it runs but when i run it directly due to some thread i think it creates .zip.tmp for its own use... and tries to edit it... thereby creating a mess..

Comment: Why 'string ZipPath' function argument in your windows app have color like a class?

Comment: Write a complete method which works in console application and doesn't works in windows application. The code you shows is already different, so no, you are not using the *same code*. To example `ZipPath`, what is the value of that parameter?

Comment: No, it is a variable only. It is just some Problem with Stack overFlow editor.

Comment: No, it is not different. Only the zip path is taken by the user in Windows Forms. In Console Application I have written it manually. This Windows form also runs some time.

Comment: When you say it throws an error, what is the exception message.

Comment: Could not find file 'C:\Work\Zip\PATHDATA DT2.zip.151.tmp'. FileNotFoundException is thrown. It creates a Temporary zip file sometime. I have seen its instance been generated at runtime in Windows Explorer.

Comment: in your console app here's the input path "C:/Work/Zip/PATHDATA DT2.zip" right? In winform can you paste here the ZipPath value that you used?

Comment: deleted answer as it was not suitable for you..
Working set @
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4qc0v9um703mbz/ZipUpdator.zip

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that some other Thread has opened that zip. Than my function was creating a temporary zip and that was creating Problem.

`zipFile.Close();`

was added to close the zip file that has been opened.

Thank you all for your advice.

Comment: whole discussion seems meaningless as you changed your question, error everything..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Make sure u use currentDirectory() where executable running**

```
private void settingAttributeinZipppedXML(string ZipPath)
{
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\PATHDATA DT2.zip");
    zipFile.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (ZipEntry ze in zipFile)
    {
        if (ze.Name == "SOURCEDATACONFIG.XML")
        {
            using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(zipFile.GetInputStream(ze)))
            {
                XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XDoc.Load(s);
                XmlNodeList NodeList = XDoc.SelectNodes(@"R/I");
                foreach (XmlNode Node in NodeList)
                {
                    XmlElement Elem = (XmlElement)Node;
                    Elem.SetAttribute("url", "12");
                }
                XDoc.Save("SOURCEDATACONFIG.XML");
            }
            zipFile.Add(ze.Name);
        }
    }
    zipFile.CommitUpdate();
}
```

Comment: sorry about that ..I checked forms too it went well with me..working

Comment: Use ICsharp from this link http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/Download.aspx

Working set @ https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4qc0v9um703mbz/ZipUpdator.zip

Comment: I think so. I will use some other method then.

Comment: Yes, it is working. But that is the problem, why am I getting error sometimes. If you can see the stack trace now.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine` is work only in console application. so not display any output, seems your application is windows form application.

if you want show output on Console using `Console.WriteLine` withing the windows form application just **add this property** and call it from the **main form constructor**.then it open with console as well.

```
 public InsertNames()
 {
   AllocConsole();
   InitializeComponent();
 }

  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  private static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Comment: That is not the problem. If you see my windows Form version it is different. Console.Writeline is not used there. That function only goes and edit the attribute in a xml file inside a zip file. That is the main task.